# Angular JS Binding Waiting Until Input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets

I'm working with Angular JS and Socket.io in an attempt to develop a simple chat room.  I got the client side working great when not plugged into sockets.  After I added the socket communication, however, the binding is messing up.

I type in the message and hit send.  addMessage is fired and then the 'chat message' socket event is fired.  However, the UI does not get updated until I type another letter or click send again.  Then the binding works its magic and the UI adds the message.

Any ideas?

js file

```
//Receive Socket message.
//Runs but UI does not update.
//UI updates on user's next input
$scope.socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
    var message = new Message(msg);
    $scope.messages.splice(0, 0, message);
    $scope.clear();
});

//Add Message, sends to socket
$scope.addMessage = function () {
  if($scope.validate()) {
    var message = new Message($scope.message);
    $scope.socket.emit('chat message', message.text);
  }
};
```

html file

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="addMessage()">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
            <input type="text" ng-model="message" placeholder="What's up?" class="form-control" ng-change="validate()">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add"/>
                </span>
            </input>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<div ui-sortable ng-model="messages">
    <div ng-repeat="message in messages"  style="padding:5px 10px;">
        <p>{{ message.text }}</p>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you try to add `$scope.$apply()` after the `$scope.clear()`? I never used `ng-form` and I would be surprised if it didn't digest the scope for you but maybe we are missing some pieces.

Comment: @floribon $scope.$apply() worked! Thank you! If you add it as an answer I will gladly accept it. If you could also explain what that does I would appreciate it.

Comment: @RyanTankersley, Angular does not "know" when an async operation has completed to know when to apply the changes (i.e. start a $digest cycle). `$scope.$apply` triggers that manually.

Comment: Alright I answered and added some more info in a immediately following update. Not sure how your `socket` object look like but you may want to do the work around it so it's fixed once for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may miss some context, but it all looks like you are updating your `$scope` outside of an Angular digest cycle, usually in a asynchronous code block that comes from a server call or `setTimeout` for instance.

Angular is not aware that the scope has been updated in such async context, and will not refresh the DOM until the next digest cycle (triggered for instance by some keyboard input in your case).

In order to force Angular to digest manually, you need to call `$scope.apply`, either as is after the updates:

```
$scope.socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
  var message = new Message(msg);
  $scope.messages.splice(0, 0, message);
  $scope.clear();
  $scope.apply();
});
```

Or by doing the updates within its callback like this:

```
$scope.socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
  $scope.$apply(function() {
    var message = new Message(msg);
    $scope.messages.splice(0, 0, message);
    $scope.clear();
  });
});
```

(The advantage being that Angular will handle and delegate any error thrown).

**UPDATE**: Ok I am just realizing you are using a custom `$scope.socket` event emitter, I thought it was a regular `$scope.$emit` on first read. So the clean way to do this would be to apply the scope directly within the `socket.emit` function. If that is a service, you can inject `$rootScope` within this service and wrap the emission within a `$rootScope.apply(...)`. Or use `$timeout`. Or if it is a totally not-angular thing, it's ok to not mess it up with angular thingies and either wrap it into an angular service, or simply `$apply` your scope whenever you need (but that is the least clean solution).